# Metal insert of 3D print with solder cup

Tags: post-processing

These are metal inserts for 3D prints:

[image: Photo of threaded brass inserts]

What I want to do is use them as a connector. A metal pin will insert them (the male connector) and it will have contact with the metal inserts.

I just want to have connectivity with a PCB as well, via soldering cables.

So my question is, are there metal inserts that have outputs where I can solder wires?
Or, maybe metal inserts that end up as a solder cup?

For reference, these are solder cups:

[image: Photo of a solder cup]

EDIT:
Perhaps if i add the dimensions of the male pin, it can make the process of answering easier.

[image]

The male pin is `2.3 mm wide` and `6mm high`.

Comment: The `metal-parts` tag is for casting from printed positives or molds or direct metal printing. you are asking about `post-processing`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for heat-insert female sockets...

[JST-connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JST_connector) don't exist as heat set parts, but you could include a void for the socket to go in.

You can buy DuPont-style cups that lead to a thin pin, which then is pushed into the female connector. Those contain a piece that acts as a spring to ensure good connectivity. Those female connectors don't exist as heat-set but can be bought without a plastic shroud for mounting in your own hardware with defined holes by physical interaction with the shell.

What you want is an insert that is not threaded but has one or more springs on the inside that press on the pin, akin to a phone connector shown below, where the metal "legs" connect to the different sections and one at the base acts as locking. The most simple design of this type would be a mono plug that also offers ground and a way to give a solid connection between the parts. However, the design of the needed springy bits inside makes it impossible for these to exist as a heat-insert - you can't heat these evenly or melt a path.

[image: Inside of a Phone Connector jack]

The only way to ensure good contact with a connecter that can be heat-set would either require the pin to screw into the insert, or the pin to be spring-loaded against a flat insert. The latter can be done by either using a solid metal slug as an inset or by retrofitting a normal inset with a screw that creates such a surface. However, spring-loaded connectors require some sort of physical interlock to get the parts in position and securely connected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your wonderful answer. Unfortunately, i did not understand many things. Your answer was great, it was my incompetence and lack of experience that made it hard to understand it. You proposed many solutions, but then you backed up because it was unfeasible. Which is the most practical way to do this? I just want my design to have female connectors. This proved to be a much harder problem than what i had originally imagined. PS, I edited my question with a picture that details the dimensions of the male pin (That will insert the female connector i want in my design).

Comment: @user1584421 none of the proposed solutions is a heat set part. The question what is best depends on the geometry of the surrounding part. If the pin needs to retain the connection and bear load, something like the phone jack might work. If it is a stress free connection that can be made a little before the parts are merged and separated after they are taken apart, JST works. If the connector can just get into position and then is arrested, spring-loaded flat connectors can work.